# clock_nanosleep - same pointer for request and remain?

Tags: c++, linux

Is it safe to submit the same object to clock_nanosleep in the request and remain parameters?

```
do {
   ret = clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0,  &t, &t);
} while (ret == EINTR);
```

I'm currently researching a phenomenon where the system sometimes never leaves that loop (although it usually does).

Regards

Comment: Doesn't look safe to me.  You are writing to an object you are reading from.

Comment: I think you're updating an object _after_ reading it, and this usage looks normal to me.

Comment: Any reason you would use this instead of [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to submit the same object to clock_nanosleep in the request and remain parameters?

In a POSIX-conforming environment at least, it's fine.

From the [POSIX `clock_nanosleep` doc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_nanosleep.html),

> The rqtp and rmtp arguments can point to the same object.

For LINUX specifically, I can't see anything in my local manpage about this, at least not explicitly prohibiting it. The non-NULL `remain` timespec is only written to if the call is already going to return, with an incomplete relative sleep: it doesn't need to read the request timespec again during or after this.

The manpage does additionally say (of the remain timespec)

> This value can then be used to call clock_nanosleep() again and complete a (relative) sleep.

in which case it's certainly desirable for `clock_nanosleep` to write it back into the same variable.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find this stated that explicitly in several docs about clock_nanosleep I found with google. Do you know if clock_nanosleep has any internal mutexes it shares with other kernel functions?

Comment: Parking your thread will almost certainly require access to some shared scheduler state, so it's certainly plausible. Have you tried attaching `strace` to the thread when the loop is hung? At least you'd be able to verify the arguments are what you expected ...